# Why rails download csv file when I want to show html using render :text or html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's simple.. 
when I write it in my controller like this.

```
def index 
@articles = News.order(:id)
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.csv { render text: @articles.to_csv}
 end
end
```

and in news.rb

```
def self.to_csv
 CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << column_names
  all.each do |product|
    csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
 end
end
```

What I expected when I open my site(http://localhost:3000/mycontroller.csv) is shows the text in my screen.
However, it just download csvfile..... Even when I changed render text to html.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Maybe is related to: http://superuser.com/questions/126354/how-can-i-make-google-chrome-display-a-plain-text-http-response-rather-than-dow

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController

 respond_to :html, :json, :csv

   def index
     @modelnames = Modelname.all
     respond_with(@modelnames)
   end
 end
```